# Modify existing Key of HashMap In Java

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm working with HashMap since few days, and facing below weird situation.

Case 1:Changed Key which is already existing in HashMap, and print HashMap
Case 2: Changed key which is already existing in HashMap and Put that key again into the HashMap. Print HashMap.

Please find below code as well as two different output of two case.

Could you please anyone let me know, whats going on in below code.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Set;

class Emp{
    private String id ;
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Emp(String id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Emp other = (Emp) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Emp [id=" + id + "]";
    }

}
public class HashMapChanges {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Emp e1 = new Emp("1");
        Emp e2 = new Emp("2");
        Emp e3 = new Emp("3");
        Emp e4 = new Emp("4");

        HashMap<Emp, String> hm = new HashMap<Emp,String>();

        hm.put(e1,"One");
        hm.put(e2,"Two");
        hm.put(e3,"Three");
        hm.put(e4,"Four");

        e1.setId("5");

        /** Uncomment below line to get different output**/
        //hm.put(e1,"Five-5");

        Set<Emp> setEmpValue = hm.keySet();
        for(Emp e : setEmpValue){
            System.out.println("Key"+ e +" Value "+ hm.get(e));
        }
    }
}
```

Output of above code :

```
KeyEmp [id=2] Value Two  
KeyEmp [id=5] Value null  
KeyEmp [id=4] Value Four  
KeyEmp [id=3] Value Three
```

Output After uncommenting line

```
KeyEmp [id=5] Value Five-5  
KeyEmp [id=2] Value Two  
KeyEmp [id=5] Value Five-5  
KeyEmp [id=4] Value Four  
KeyEmp [id=3] Value Three
```

Answer (score 4):

Using mutable objects as keys in a Map is not permitted when the key used to determine its location in the Map is mutable.

From the Javadoc for `java.util.Map<K,V>`:

> Note: great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as map keys. The behavior of a map is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is a key in the map.

You are violating the contract required of map keys because your `Emp` object is mutable, and the change modifies the attribute used to determine where in the map the key resides.

The result is undefined behavior.

I suspect you have misunderstood the `Map` concept, based on your code, but without understanding what you're actually trying to achieve we really cannot help further.  I suggest you ask a new question explaining your actual goals.

Answer (score -3):

You overwrite the `hashCode()` and `equals()` method ,
then ,the Map's key is the hashCode result.
then `id=1` and `id=5` are two different items.

You can comment the two methods and try again.