# Internal implementation of hashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I am understanding hashMap internal implementation and i need some help regarding the same. HashMap store data by using linkedlist in java 8 it is using tree data structure. 
below is the node Node class constructor could you please help me to understand why node is having hash value of the key?

```
Node(int hash, K key, V value, Node<K,V> next) {
            this.hash = hash;
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
            this.next = next;
        }
```

Comment: Don't you think it would be easier to understand how it works by reading from some external source instead of internal implementation itself? Even a Wiki article would help a lot: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Comment: Well, calculating the hash could be costly so caching it is wise. Also note that the decision whether to use a linked list or a tree doesn't depend on the Java version (although there might be internal changes) but rather on the size of the list: a short list often is easier to use and faster than a tree so you'll mostly get a list and only if there a too many collisions will it be converted into a tree (via the protected method `treeifyBin(...)`).

Comment: [The source code for Java 8's HashMap](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java), for those who wish to read it.

Answer (score 2):

You use the hashes to compute the placement of an element within the HashMap. It would be supremely inefficient if adding a key to your HashMap required re-computation of the hashes every time a collision needed to be [resolved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution). Not only that, but some objects may have expensive hash functions (for example, String `hashCode` goes through every character in the String). It would always be desirable to compute such functions once and cache them for later (since you should [**not**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48941899/5699679) change hashCode/equals for an object placed within a Map).

Let's consider a HashMap that is half full (`n/2`), with independent elements being placing into the entry set. There is a `1/2` probability of collision (minimum) for any given element being added. The amount of entries possible to fill the HashMap is `n`, but the default load factor is 0.75, which means we have `3n/4 - n/2 = n/4` entries left to fill. All of these entries must be without hash collisions, as we save time for each collision (by caching). Assuming the maximum possible probability of `1/2` for not having a collision, we see that we have probability `1/2`<sup>`n/4`</sup> of no collisions occurring before HashMap expansion. This means that for any sizeable HashMap (`n=29+`, out of which only 0.5*29=(about 15) keys have to be filled), there is a greater than 99% chance that you get time savings off of caching hash values.

tl;dr It saves time, especially when collisions become frequent for addition/lookups.